# Trying To Get XML Child Elements

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to use simplexml to get the contents of child elements but am getting blanks

```
$results = simplexml_load_string($payload);


echo $results->{'OBX.5.1'} . "<br>";
```

All I get is 
 returned.

XML below. Any ideas?

```
<OBX>
        <OBX.1>
            <OBX.1.1>1</OBX.1.1>
        </OBX.1>
        <OBX.2>
            <OBX.2.1>NM</OBX.2.1>
        </OBX.2>
        <OBX.3>
            <OBX.3.1>2951-2</OBX.3.1>
            <OBX.3.2>S Sodium:</OBX.3.2>
            <OBX.3.3>LN</OBX.3.3>
        </OBX.3>
        <OBX.4/>
        <OBX.5>
            <OBX.5.1>144</OBX.5.1>
        </OBX.5>
        <OBX.6>
            <OBX.6.1>mmol/L</OBX.6.1>
            <OBX.6.2>mmol/L</OBX.6.2>
        </OBX.6>

    </OBX>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the full path to the node in order to get its value.  In this case, `OXB.5` is the parent of `OBX.5.1`, so you need to include it in the chain:

```
echo $results->{'OBX.5'}->{'OBX.5.1'} . "<br>";
```

Comment: If I was a woman I'd have your babies. Your code didn't work but it did give me the clues I needed to fix it myself.   echo $results->{'OBX'}->{'OBX.5'}->{'OBX.5.1'};